# Server Trust Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

Our app is in production and today we came across an issue "The Certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server.name” which could put your confidential information at risk.

We are using connection over https.

There is no such issue earlier. Why the same is giving this error now. Its not even connecting to server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your SSL certificate just expired.